# Newsletter preferences - add to database

Tags: html, database, forms, post, newsletter

I want to add a submit or save button that adds the customers answer to the database table 'newsletter'. Anyone got any idea how to go about this? The customer will be logged in already for other details to add to the table, which I may be able to figure out on my own.

```
<div id="newsletter-settings">
                                <h3 style="margin-left:0; padding:0; font-size:14px; background:none; margin:0;">Your Newsletter Settings</h3>
                                <p>You can edit your newsletter preferences by checking the boxes below to suit your requirements.</p>

                                <form method="post">
                                    <label for="recieve-newsletter">Do you wish to receive the Make A Will Now email newsletter?</label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="recieve-newsletter" value="Yes" /><span>Yes</span>
                                    <input type="radio" name="recieve-newsletter" value="No" style="margin-left:20px;" /><span>No, not at the moment</span>

                                    <label for="newsletter-partners" style="margin-top:20px;">Do you wish to receive emails from carefully selected partners?</label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="newsletter-partners" value="Yes" /><span>Yes</span>
                                    <input type="radio" name="newsletter-partners" value="No" style="margin-left:20px;" /><span>No, not at the moment</span>
                                </form>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Are you using mysql db? Have you connect the db in your page and you just need the query?

Comment: At the table newsletter you store only the customers answer?

Comment: With their name, email address and id which I can fetch from the users table. I also want to know how to add a save button so they wont need to keep answering the question. Im new to html you see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can get the value of the checked button with jquery:

```
var val = $('input:radio[name=recieve-newsletter]:checked').val();
```

Then you can say to your submit button to insert the answer at your db with a function like this:

```
function insert(){ mysql_query("insert into newsletter (answer) values ('$val')");}
```

Now the button would be like that

```
<input type="submit" OnClick="insert();" value="submit your answer">
```